# Run Scala Dotty project using Intellij IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dotty, scala-3

I created a basic Scala Dotty project using Dotty template and import the project to IntelliJ IDE.

Everything works fine when I use the `sbt` command line.

When I try to build or run it inside IntelliJ IDE, I got following errors:

```
Error:scalac: Multiple 'scala-library*.jar' files (scala-library-0.9.0-RC1.jar, scala-library-2.12.6.jar) in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK sbt: ch.epfl.lamp:dotty-library_0.9:0.9.0-RC1:jar
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IDE support for Dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/usage/ide-support.html)

> Currently, the only IDE we officially support is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Anyway when you import a project to IntelliJ IDEA check "use sbt shell". At least for me after that a [test project](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/67029506d79e1eb10daf8872a62db9da) compiles and runs with Ctrl+Shift+F10.

[image: import]

It's possible that not everything will work. For example [Dotty macros](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/a95c9fa500c6129f8143690835046cff) don't but if I compile and run manually then they do.

Comment: IntelliJ silently dropped the experimental support for Dotty there was, https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/6203.