# How to execute dotty code from Visual Studio Code UI

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, dotty, scala-3

I'm trying to use `Visual Studio Code` to run dotty code. I started IDE using `sbt launchIDE` according to the instruction from [this page](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/usage/ide-support.html), and I also installed `Dotty Language Server` and `Code Runner` extensions. Dotty is installed using `brew` and I can compile and execute dotty code from CMD.

The problem is that I cannot run this code from `Visual Studio Code` because `Code Runner` is trying to execute it using scala instead of dotty.

Can't find any useful configuration to adjust this plugin to use dotty.

Is there any way to make it works from Visual Studio Code UI?

Comment: Your question needs some more info on your environment e.g. what OS you are on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone repository https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-example-project (it's mentioned at the page https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/usage/getting-started.html) and run

```
sbt launchIDE
```

(this is mentined at https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/usage/ide-support.html).

The code should be **run** with scala (runtime is the same). If the code is **compiled** with scalac instead of dotty this can mean that either scalaVersion is wrong in `build.sbt` or dotty sbt plugin is not switched on in `plugins.sbt`.

[image]

*build.sbt*

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "dottydemo",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "0.13.0-RC1"
)
```

*plugins.sbt*

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.lamp" % "sbt-dotty" % "0.3.0")
```

Also you can try IntelliJ IDEA (although it's not officially supported) [Run Scala Dotty project using Intellij IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288297/run-scala-dotty-project-using-intellij-ide)

Comment: Yes. All my config files contain correct configurations and versions and I'm using `sbt launchIDE`, but when I do "Run Code" from UI it compiles code using scala instead of dotty. Can't compile code from your screenshot too. `sbt compile` and `sbt run` commands work well for me. Maybe I need some extra sbt extension on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko Did you manage to resolve your issue? If so, how?

Comment: @TimoMeijer Unfortunately, not. I just started compiling and running using command line tools.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko I'm now doing it with a Task(ctrl-shift-p -> task). I made tasks for both `sbt run` and `sbt ~run`, which works great for me to run/test the code